# Disabling inertial scroll in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to disable inertial scrolling in Eclipse Luna?

This *feature* is not good for me. Moreover it appears bugged and it continues scrolling for many seconds after I removed my hand from the touchpad.

Comment: What platform is this (Mac / Linux / Windows)? Eclipse / SWT just uses native controls for this sort of thing.

Comment: In Mars on Ubuntu, I see this problem. The main editor view either has inertial scrolling or is just incredibly unresponsive, while the other views do not. Additionally, scrolling the editor window requires a lot of CPU time.